# Can two users share the same Request.UserHostAddress?

Tags: http, asp.net, fraud

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC-5 web application, which is available to public users (no login is required). And I need to prevent the same user from submitting more than 5 "contact us" requests within an hour. So I need a way to differentiate if the Request I am receiving is coming from the same user or not.

I found the `Request.UserHostAddress` , which will contain the user IP (if I am not wrong the public IP). but my question is will this value be unique per user all over the world? Or could users share this value?
If the answer is that users might share the `Request.UserHostAddress`, then which value will give me better way to "authenticate" the user?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this address can be shared by multiple users. For example:

- Mobile phone providers often route their 3G/4G traffic for their subscribers via the same public IP.
- Some ISPs have shared public IP addresses - historically notably AOL.
- Corporations often have single or multiple gateways, meaning their employee traffic will be shared via the same external interface.

In your case you are not really authenticating clients based upon their IP, you are attempting to rate limit them. One solution could be to allow as many submissions from an IP, however if you detect over say five per hour coming from the same location then you could display a [CAPTCHA](http://www.captcha.net/) that has to be completed.

Google are attempting to make these easier for people to complete with their [Recaptcha v2](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) project.

Comment: thanks for the reply... but from my own reading is that i can first check for "Request.ServerVariables["X-FORWARDED-FOR"]" which will show the IP if the user is behind a proxy and if the value is not there i can check the UserHostAddress does this sound more reliable,, so if the user is behind a proxy i will check his Request.ServerVariables["X-FORWARDED-FOR"] other wise if the user is not behind a proxy then using UserHostaddress will this work ?? can you adivce ?

Comment: The problem is that `X-FORWARDED-FOR` is not sent by all proxies. Additionally there is nothing stopping a user without a proxy from spoofing the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header. You would have to maintain a list of proxies that you trust if you wanted to use this header. At the end of the day it is a contact us form, so accidentally showing a Recaptcha v2 every now and again would not be a massive hit on the UX.

Comment: but i want to simplify the process to send contact us form, so i do not want to show Recaptcha for them,, and still even with using Recaptcha will not prevent users from manually submitting the form.. so which approach is best suited in my case ? second question regarding the public IP do you mean that 3G providers will be exposing certain public IPs so all users using the 3G on their mobile phones might be sharing the same userhostaddress ??

Comment: Yes, that could be the case with 3G. You can't stop anonymous users from submitting your form. If you blocked IP they would simply use a proxy or TOR or reset their router to get a new dynamic IP from their ISP. You _can_ make it harder, which is where the CAPTCHA comes in. What type of attack are you trying to prevent if the worst that a user can do is manually submit a contact us form? Does the form enter them in a competition, or is there some other advantage in multiple submissions?

Answer (score 1):

If you get user IP with proper method that grab the user network global IP, it will be always unique. But users can send multiple proxy request at a time. To prevent that use captcha along with your IP validation. Than it should work perfect!

Comment: but how i am going to validate the IP, seems that checking public IPs will not work as in the other answer, he mentioned that mobile phone provider share a set of public ips so i will end up blocking users even if they did not submit any form before !!

Comment: Agree! I am not sure but you may try with combination of public + private IP of request.

Comment: Another normal way is to store something securely in user's browser cookie and manage it through scripting. For which you have to ask users to keep their cookie enabled to load your site.

Comment: i am already storing AntiForgeryToken and i am checking ths token on server,, but this will prevent hacking my application using automated tools,, but still normal users can keep submitting contact us form ,, is this correct ?

Comment: you mentioned "you may try with combination of public + private IP of request" ,, but how i can get the private IP of a request does "X-FORWARDED-FOR" satisfy this ? so i can combine both UserHostAddress + X-FORWARDED-FOR?